# ElasticSearch doesn't find my script

Tags: elasticsearch

Somehow elasticsearch (version 1.5.2) doesn't find my script `sorting` in `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/`. I gave the folder and the file itself file permissions for ES and have in my elasticsearch.yml:

`path.conf: /etc/elasticsearch`

Still I get a *ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Unable to find on disk script sorting]* when querying:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "file": "sorting",
          "lang": "groovy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to enable scripts from disc somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts should be placed in `/scripts` folder, under `/config` one and it should have a `.groovy` extension. From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting):

> Save the contents of the script as a file called `config/scripts/my_script.groovy` on every data node in the cluster

And, also, your query should use `script_file` not `file`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script_file": "sorting",
          "lang": "groovy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Declaring the scripting language in the query is not enough - I had to add `.groovy` also to the file - you are right. Under Ubuntu the config folder is by default `/etc/elasticsearch` though and this is where the subfolder `scripts` needs to be located.

Answer (score 0):

The script may be missing because the script was rejected by elastic search.

Tail your elasticsearch log file and ensure that no errors are thrown when the script file is saved.